# how to get custom attribute value on my order page

Tags: magento2

I have overridden phtml files and respective block, i.e. defaultRendere.php file and where I created getCustomAttribute class its return successfully any test data, But I want return Custom Attribute value for that I tried the following Code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                  ->load($this->getItem()->getId());
$test=$product->getData('attribute_name'); 
return $test;
```

but its return nothing .. `$this->getItem()->getId())` return product id.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code :

```
protected $_product;

public function __construct(
    ..........
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    ..........
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_product = $product;
}

public function yourFunctionName(){
    $_product = $this->_product->load('your product id');
    $myattribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Your_Attribute_Code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    return $myattribute;
}
```

It may be helpful for you.

Comment: okay! yeah i will try this also , right now its solved by adding "$_item->getProduct()->getData(''my_attribute'');" on default.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
     \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
```

or

```
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
```

Comment: okay! yeah i will try this also , right now its solved by adding "$_item->getProduct()->getData(''my_attribute'');"